# How to show Array of images in recyclerview based on headline object from json Android

Tags: android, arrays, json, android-activity, android-recyclerview

I have received a json data from rest api. This data contains id, title, body, an array of images "appImages" and a teaserImage. Now I deserialize the json in controller class. I have creted two adapters. First adpter is used for recyclerview. This recycler view is showing the title and and teasetImage. this portion working. If user click on item it redirect to detail activity, where he can see teaserImage as cover image, and the body as description. Now this layout I oroganised this way, at fisrt the ImageView for cover Image, TextView for Description. And below description I have created a recyclerView to show the array of images. The CoverImage and description of detail cativity is working well. For recyclerview I have created another Adpater, this adapter is used to show all the images based on the title of news. But I stuch to show those images in recyclerview. I have explained in deatil in my code.

My controller class

```
public class NewsController {
private static final String TAG = NewsController.class.getSimpleName();
private UserCallbackListener mListener;
private NewsRestApiManager mApiManager;
private AppImage appImages;

public NewsController(UserCallbackListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
    mApiManager = new NewsRestApiManager();
}

public void startFetching(){

    mApiManager.getNewsApi().getNews(new Callback<String>() {

        @Override
        public void success(String s, Response response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "JSON :: " + s);

            try {
                JSONArray array = new JSONArray(s);

                for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);

                    NewsModel news = new NewsModel();
                    news.setTitle( jsonObject.optString( "title") );
                    news.setBody( jsonObject.optString( "body" ) );

                    ArrayList<AppImage> list = new ArrayList();
                    JSONArray imageArray =jsonObject.getJSONArray("appImages");
                    if (imageArray.length() > 1) {
                        for(int j=0; j<imageArray.length();j++){
                            appImages  = new AppImage();
                            appImages.setSrc(new JSONArray( s ).getJSONObject( i ).getJSONArray( "appImages" ).getJSONObject( j ).getString( "src" ));

                            list.add(appImages);

                        }

                    }
                    news.setAppImages( list );
                    TeaserImageSmall coverImage=new TeaserImageSmall();
                    coverImage.setSrc( new JSONArray( s ).getJSONObject( i ).getJSONObject( "teaserImageSmall" ).getString( "src" ));
                    news.setTeaserImageSmall(coverImage);
                    mListener.onFetchProgressNews(news);


                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                mListener.onFetchFailed();
            }

            mListener.onFetchComplete();
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error :: " + error.getMessage());
            mListener.onFetchComplete();
        }
    });

}
public interface UserCallbackListener{
    void onFetchStart();
    void onFetchProgressNews(NewsModel news);
    void onFetchProgressNews(List<NewsModel> userList);


    void onFetchComplete();
    void onFetchFailed();
}
```

My adapter class for News Recyclerview. This is perfect now.

```
    public class NewsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsAdapter.NewsHolder>
    ........
 public void addNews(NewsModel news) {
        Log.d(TAG,news.getTeaserImageSmall().getSrc());
        mNews.add(news);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(NewsHolder holder, int position) {
    final NewsModel currentNews = mNews.get(position);
    Picasso.with(holder.itemView.getContext());
    Picasso.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load(currentNews.getTeaserImageSmall().getSrc()).into( holder.newsImage );

    holder.newsHeadline.setText(currentNews.getTitle());

    holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent i=new Intent(context,DetailNews.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            i.putExtra("src",currentNews.getTeaserImageSmall().getSrc());
            i.putExtra("title",currentNews.getTitle());
            i.putExtra("body",currentNews.getBody());
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Now Another Adapter for Array of images which will show in detail activity of news page.

**Edited Adapter Class**

```
    public class NewsImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsImageAdapter.ImageHolder> {

    public static String TAG = NewsImageAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
    private Context context;
    private List<AppImage> appImageList;
    DetailNews detailNews  = new DetailNews  ();


    public NewsImageAdapter(List<AppImage> imageObject,Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.appImageList = imageObject;
    }
    public void addImage(AppImage appImage) {
        Log.d(TAG,appImage.getSrc());
        appImageList.add(appImage);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    @Override
    public ImageHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.newsdetail_image_row,parent,false);
        return new ImageHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ImageHolder holder, int position) {
        final AppImage currentImage=appImageList.get(position);
        //getting error for current news, 
        detailNews .navigate(context, appImageList, currentNews.getTeaserImageSmall().getSrc(), currentNews.getTitle(),currentNews.getBody()); 
        Picasso.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load(currentImage.getSrc()).into( holder.images);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return imageObject.size();
    }

    public class ImageHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public ImageView images;

        public ImageHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            images= itemView.findViewById(R.id.news_image);
        }
    }
}
```

Detail activity of news where I am shoing coverImage and description at this moment. But I also want to show the list of images below the description. I would like to how can I implement that.

**Edited Detail Activity**

```
public class DetailNews extends AppCompatActivity{


public class DetailNews extends AppCompatActivity{

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private NewsImageAdapter adapter;
private List<AppImage> imageList= new ArrayList<>();
private NewsController mController;
private CardView cardview;
private ImageView _coverImage;
private TextView _newsHeading;
private TextView _description;
private TextView _newsDate;
private static List<AppImage> appImageList,mAppImageList;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.news_detail);

    //newsObject=getAllImageList();

    // setting up views and stuff
    setUpUIViews();

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    //RECEIVE DATA
    Log.e("_coverImage",""+_coverImage);
    String coverImage = intent.getStringExtra ("src");
    String heading=intent.getExtras().getString("title");
    //String newsDate=intent.getExtras().getString("date");
    String description=intent.getExtras().getString("body");

    //BIND DATA

    Picasso.with(this).load(coverImage ).into(_coverImage);
    _newsHeading.setText(heading);
    // _newsDate.setText(newsDate);
    _description.setText(description);
    Linkify.addLinks( _description,Linkify.WEB_URLS );

}

private void setUpUIViews() {
    _coverImage=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.news_cover);
    _newsHeading=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.heading);
    _description=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.news_description);
    _newsDate=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.date);

    cardview=(CardView) findViewById(R.id.cardView);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.image_list);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(DetailNews.this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    adapter = new NewsImageAdapter(imageList,getApplicationContext() );
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        finish();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void navigate(Context activity, List<AppImage> appImageList, String  src, String  title, String  body) {

    mAppImageList = appImageList;

    Intent intent = new Intent(activity, DetailNews  .class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.putExtra("src",src);
    intent .putExtra("title",title);
    intent .putExtra("body",body);
    activity.startActivity(intent);
    try {
        if (activity instanceof NewasPage) { //Error for news
            ((NewsPage) activity).finish();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }


}
```

My Mdel Class is

```
public class NewsModel {

@Expose
private String _id;

@Expose
private String body;

@Expose
private String title;

@Expose
private List<AppImage> appImages;

public List<AppImage> getAppImages() {
    return appImages;
}

public void setAppImages(List<AppImage> appImages) {
    this.appImages = appImages;
}
```

AppImage Model Class

```
    public class AppImage {
    @Expose
    private String _id;

    @Expose
    private String alt;

    @Expose
    private String src;

    public String get_id() {
        return _id;
    }

    public void set_id(String _id) {
        this._id = _id;
    }

    public String getAlt() {
        return alt;
    }

    public void setAlt(String alt) {
        this.alt = alt;
    }

    public String getSrc() {
        return src;
    }

    public void setSrc(String src) {
        this.src = src;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where you are passing appImages to the second activity?

Comment: @SibinDavis in that case, I have stucked, in controller class I have created interface onFetchProgressNews(NewsModel news); then on news adaprer I have creted method addNews that is added news in Mainactivity of new. But ib this case how can I add imgelist in detail activity

Comment: It's better to use Fragment for the second page.Then it is easy to pass objects.

Comment: I got news in main recyclerview by implementing NewsController.UserCallbackListener , then  mController = new NewsController(NewsPage.this);
        mController.startFetching(); then  @Override
    public void onFetchProgressNews(NewsModel news) {
        adapter.addNews(news);
    }

Comment: But I already set my code as activity. i do not want to change it. also Fragment handling is still complecated for me

Comment: ok.Then there are three ways : use parcelable or serializable or create a setter method in the second activity.

Comment: @SibinDavis Could you please explain me based on my code. I just stuck with this issue from the mornig. nothing is solved my problem yet

Comment: Ok .I will show in answer

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152734/discussion-between-ktina-and-sibin-davis).

Answer (score 0):

In DetailNews  Activity, add a method

```
private static List<AppImage> appImageList mAppImageList; 



            public void navigate(Context activity, List<AppImage> appImageList,String  src,String  title,String  body) {

                    mAppImageList = appImageList;

                    Intent intent = new Intent(activity, DetailNews  .class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                 intent.putExtra("src",src);
                intent .putExtra("title",title);
                intent .putExtra("body",body);
                    activity.startActivity(intent);
                    try {
                        if (activity instanceof FirstActivity) {
                            ((FirstActivity) activity).finish();
                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
```

And in the adapter do as

```
DetailNews  detailNews  = new DetailNews  ();
                                        detailNews  .navigate(context, appImageList, currentNews.getTeaserImageSmall().getSrc(), currentNews.getTitle(),currentNews.getBody());
```

Comment: is this line correct private static List<AppImage> appImageList mAppImageList;

Comment: Ya . It is the imagelist to use in DetailNews   activity.

Comment: this line is shoing error (activity instanceof FirstActivity) {
                            ((FirstActivity) activity).finish()

Comment: I already created Class of NewsPage, that is my first activity. but here it sis showig error

Comment: Where Can I write this line? detailNews .navigate(context, appImageList, currentNews.getTeaserImageSmall().getSrc(), currentNews.getTitle(),currentNews.getBody()); in which adapter

Comment: Hello @Sibin I alredy got headline image , body , date in detail activity. I have updated my code. then do I need to passthis agin. because I only need list of images in recyclerview, for the second half of detail activity

Comment: Replace firstActivity with NewsPage.

Comment: And you have to call the method from NewsAdapter ,by replacing that intent.

Comment: Ya . you have to pass all of them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152821/discussion-between-ktina-and-sibin-davis).